# Append parameter in url without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, append, pushstate

I am using following code to append param to url. This is working fine but when parameter is appended in url, page is getting reloaded. I want to use this functionality without reloading the page .

```
function insertParam(key, value)
{
    key = escape(key); value = escape(value);

    var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');


    var i=kvp.length; var x; while(i--) 
    {
        x = kvp[i].split('=');

        if (x[0]==key)
        {
                x[1] = value;
                kvp[i] = x.join('=');
                    alert('sdfadsf');
                break;
        }
    }

    if(i<0) {kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');}

    //this will reload the page, it's likely better to store this until finished
    document.location.search = kvp.join('&'); 
    //alert(document.location.href);
```

## }

I want to add multiple params to url without reloading the page like:

- txt1
- txt2
- txt3

- link1
- link2
- link3

i want url  : "..../search.php"

after click on txt2 
i want url : "..../search.php#t_2"

after click on link2 
i want url : "..../search.php#t_1&l_2"

Comment: i want to add mutliple parameter in url like:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only do this using [`history.pushState(state, title, url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which is an HTML5 feature.

Comment: I think the OP only wants to append fragments to the url, for example  `document.location.href += '#txt'`

Comment: @NADH he never said that - the code (and the original question) talked about query parameters, not anchor fragments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature that aims to replace the use of `location.hash` with a better solution: `pushState`.

```
 window.history.pushState(data, "Title", "/new-url");
```

More information: http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate