# how to change the url without reloading

Tags: javascript, html

I have read a lot of other questions on how to change the URL with out reloading the page. This is my code that I have just wondering if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong? When I click the button it doesn't change the url. This is my exact code and not sure what I have done wrong, Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> Social Media </title>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Page1" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page1','Page1.htm');" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the new url to have /new-url onto the end. Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? What about it isn't working? What browser are you testing it in?

Comment: This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445229/append-parameter-in-url-without-reloading-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: this could help you too..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect

Comment: What's the problem or issue that you are having ?  Let us know that .

Comment: Sorry should have put in more description, I have updated it now. Basically this code just doesn't work and was wondering if anyone could help

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Page1" onclick="ChangeUrl('Page1','Page1.htm');" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeUrl(title, url) 
{
    window.history.pushState("object or string", title, url);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways.

1. `pushState` creates one new history entry
2. `replaceState` updates the current history entry

You can do something like this:

```
function changeURL(title, url)
{
    history.replaceState("", title, url);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the pushState, but I can't get it to work, just wondering if you knew what i did wrong, thanks.