# Appending parameter to URL without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate, html5-history

I know this has been asked many times before but answers were not descriptive enough to solve my problem. I don't want to change the whole URL of page. I want to append a parameter `&item=brand` on button click without refresh.

Using `document.location.search += '&item=brand';` makes the page refresh.

Using `window.location.hash = "&item=brand";` append without refresh but with a hash `#` which eliminates the usage/effect of the parameter. I tried to remove the hash after appending but that didn't work.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10445250/2321603) and many others suggest the use of HTML5 History API, specifically the `history.pushState` method, and for old browsers is to set a fragment identifier to prevent page from reloading. But how?

---

Assuming the URL is: `http://example.com/search.php?lang=en`

How can I append `&item=brand` using HTML5 pushState method or a fragment identifier so the output would be like this: `http://example.com/search.php?lang=en&item=brand` without a page refresh?

---

I hope someone can throw some light on how to use the HTML5 pushState to append a parameter to an existing/current URL. Or alternatively how to set a fragment identifier for the same purpose. A good tutorial, demo or piece of code with a little explanation would be great.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pwsubLx4/) of what I've done so far. Your answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can use the [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) or [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) methods,  e.g. :

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "new url");
```

OR

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?arg=123");
```

Example with argument:

```
var refresh = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?arg=1';    
window.history.pushState({ path: refresh }, '', refresh);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked, but surprisingly the parameter didn't apply into the system. However, it take effect when I add it manually into the URL. I will take this as an accepted answer as it solves my main question but please if you have a suggestion on why the parameter won't be applied to system when added using the `history.pushState` please tell me :) Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks, I ending up using window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?mock"); To add a url param without reload.

Comment: Browser compatibility is [somewhat good](https://caniuse.com/?search=pushState), but note that it won't work for below IE10 or (potentially) some mobile browsers.

Comment: This is not "appending" the URL. This removed a bunch of other parameters I had in my web browser's URL string. Those other parameters are important, so I'm not sure why this was the accepted answer.

Answer (score 59):

You can also use URL API if you want to add and remove params at the same time:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.set('param1', 'val1');
url.searchParams.delete('param2');
window.history.replaceState(null, null, url); // or pushState
```

Comment: Much nicer than reconstructing the URL like `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?arg=1'`

Answer (score 31):

If anyone wants to add a parameter to a more complex url (I mean, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/edit?newParameter=1), the following code worked for me:

```
var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?newParameter=1';
window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: here is the reference to this working code.
https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2015/04/08/javascript-add-query-parameter-to-current-url-without-reload/

Comment: I also add window.location.hash to the end of the new URL.

Comment: This removed a bunch of other parameters I had in my web browser's URL string. Those other parameters are important.

Answer (score 1):

Modified [Medhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917916/13124516) answer and this did the trick

```
const insertParam = (key: string, value: string) => {
    key = encodeURIComponent(key);
    value = encodeURIComponent(value);

    let kvp = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    if (kvp[0] === '') {
        const path = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?' + key + '=' + value;
        window.history.pushState({ path: path }, '', path);

    } else {
        let i = kvp.length; let x; while (i--) {
            x = kvp[i].split('=');

            if (x[0] === key) {
                x[1] = value;
                kvp[i] = x.join('=');
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i < 0) { 
            kvp[kvp.length] = [key, value].join('=');
        }

        const refresh = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?' + kvp.join('&');  
        window.history.pushState({ path: refresh }, '', refresh);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append multiple parameters in the current url without reloading the page, try this:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, `?${$.param({
   item: 'brand',
   lang: 'en',
})}`);
```

`$.param` will convert your object to `item=brand&lang=en` then just add `?` at the beginning.

The result would be: `httpts://app.com/index?item=brand&lang=en`

Answer (score -1):

```js
export function getHash(hash: string, key: string): string | undefined {
  return hash
    .split("#")
    .find((h) => h.startsWith(key))
    ?.replace(`${key}=`, "");
}
export function setHash(hash: string, key: string, value: string): string {
  let hashArray = hash.split("#").filter((h) => !h.startsWith(key));
  hashArray.push(`${key}=${value}`);
  return hashArray.length > 0
    ? hashArray.reduce((s1, s2) => `${s1}#${s2}`)
    : "";
}
export function deleteHash(hash: string, key: string): string {
  let hashArray = hash.split("#").filter((h) => !h.startsWith(key));
  return hashArray.length > 0
    ? hashArray.reduce((s1, s2) => `${s1}#${s2}`)
    : "";
}
```