# Change CSS when the current URL contains a certain string

Tags: javascript

I used this function for checking the url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("franky") > -1) {
            /* some code to change the css */;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Currently it only works when I refresh the page.

Is there a way to make it work when url change without any refresh ? Thanks

EXAMPLE : its like you have to choose a color , you click on a button to select your color , it make example.com/color.html#/red ; example.com/color.html#/blue ; example.com/color.html#/black only the color change with no refresh and i want to add specific css when url contain each string color

Comment: To clarify - did you want to change the URL? currently your code just tries to inspect it.

Comment: _is there a way to make it work so that the url changes without any refresh_ what would be the point? If you're trying to store state somewhere the URL is not the right place for it.

Comment: I think this means getting the changed URL from `history` after pushing to it e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828160/appending-parameter-to-url-without-refresh

Comment: no i dont want to change it ! i want to add custom css by specific url contain string ! it work only on refresh page but when the url change without refresh nothing appear

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to detect specific users based on the URL, and then use different CSS?  If so, this is not a good way to achieve what you want.

Comment: if you have php, try using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: in example my url change to  example.com/test/27-black/22-coffee to example.com/test/26-white/22-coffee without refresh. i want to check when url contain white , or when contain black and apply css

Comment: define the wanted css and change or add the id or class with   

$( "p" ).addClass( "yourClass" ); The corresponding css wil be applied. https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: but i want to add it on specific url contain string

Comment: Perhaps you just need to go about this a different way, take a look at this previously [answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes) and subscribe to the `popstate` event. I have not personally used it before, but it seems like it should work fine for what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#black">black</a>
<a href="#blue">blue</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    var origEvent = e.originalEvent;
    resultdata = origEvent.newURL;
    var black = resultdata.match(/black/);
    if (black){
      console.log(black);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: still not work when url changing without refresh page

Comment: but where is the url check string ?

Comment: The on hashchange function fires when a window's hash changes.
You can insert your if loop code or something inside this function to check

Comment: so how i do if i want to add css if url contain "black" ? im a noob

Comment: Hold let me post you an example

Comment: thank you very much it seem to work ! :D