# Add parameters to url without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add parameters to url without refreshing the page. I have used `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState`. I put a debugger on the function in javascript, when I debug `history.pushState`, it replaces the url, but then it changes again to the previous.

What I want to is, e.g. below is my url

```
.../?id=1
```

Now I will click on one of my filters and the url must be as follows

```
.../?id=1,2
```

Then I will click on `Search` button to apply filter. What should be the best practices?

Comment: can you post a snippet with a relevant code?

Comment: Best practice is to not try and make the browser do something it's designed not to do.  Change the Url when the search button is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending parameter to URL without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828160/appending-parameter-to-url-without-refresh)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to add parameters without refresh:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?param1=value");
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a good example to follow:

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

You can use in filters comands like: `onchange, onclick` etc. for instant modification of URL

Answer (score -2):

Better don't change your URL before you apply your filter.
Save your filter parameters in some object, and change URL after user clicks submit

Comment: This should be a comment.