# Is there any way to redirect my page on given href link without loading

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, redirect

this is my html

`<a href="http://127.1.1.0:8001/gembead/emstones.html?car=36">Car</a>`

Basically i want to redirect to this page with parameter but i dont want my page to load.
How can i do this.
I am sure there will be a solution for this.

Comment: Redirect without a page load? You'll probably need some sort of client-side routing.

Comment: You can try to do this (it works only with the same origins): `window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', 'http://127.1.1.0:8001/gembead/emstones.html?car=36');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (+info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828160/appending-parameter-to-url-without-refresh/32828207)):

```js
function withoutLoading(url) {
   window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);
}
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="withoutLoading('/gembead/emstones.html?car=36')">Car</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a new link without reloading your current page, you have to use `window.hostory.push('url')` or `window.hostory.replace('url')` on the onclick event of your button or anchor tab.