# How does this web page change URL query parameter in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html, url, address-bar

The initial URL is

```
https://robertbarakett.com/products/the-barakett-t-hoodie?option1=Blue+night&option2=S
```

I traced the HTTP requests. It only does 1 redirect:
from

```
https://robertbarakett.com/products/the-barakett-t-hoodie?option1=Blue+night&option2=S
```

to

```
https://robertbarakett.com/products/the-barakett-hoodie-black?option1=Blue%20night&option2=S.
```

However, the final URL in the address bar is

```
https://robertbarakett.com/products/the-barakett-hoodie-black?variant=31966791729263.
```

I read about changing URL without reloading page:

1. [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)
2. [Appending parameter to URL without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828160/appending-parameter-to-url-without-refresh/32828207)

Since there is no navigation history after loading the web page, it rules out `window.history.pushState`. Maybe it uses `window.history.replaceState`? I did a search in the page's source code, didn't find any use of `replaceState`. So how to verify whether it uses `replaceState` or other techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using `window.history.replaceState`

In: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0061/4134/5903/t/13/assets/theme.js?v=13437044988013674143

Its has:

```
_updateHistoryState: function(variant) {
   if (!history.replaceState || !variant) {
     return;
   }
  
   var newurl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?variant=' + variant.id;
   window.history.replaceState({path: newurl}, '', newurl);
},
```

Is the only place in the source which assigns `?variant`

Found by downloading site (right-click save-as), then doing a search for `?variant`

Comment: Amazing! I searched `variant` myself and found several reference. But how could you trace it down to that specific JS file? There are quite some JS files.

Comment: np, is lots of `variant`, but only one `?variant`. I saved the page, opened in vs-code then did a search Ctrl-Shift-F, was the only file to show up.. It would take too long to look manually through every file or request response

Comment: Just realized what you mean by "right-click save-as", that does the trick!